# How can I make vim open certain file types with specific syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, nasm

I want to make vim open all files of type *.asm with the syntax set to nasm so I don't have to type `:set syntax=nasm` every time I fire up vim.

I'm sure there's something I can put in my .vimrc file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this to your vimrc file

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.asm set filetype=nasm
```

Anytime a buffer read or creates a new file with the extension `.asm` it will format it with the `nasm` file syntax

`au` is short for `autocmd`  you can find out more by using `:h au`

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
let asmsyntax="nasm"
```

in your .vimrc